# Reducing calls to .load() in constraints

Tags: anchor, account, constraints

When using constraints with a zero-copy account that uses AccountLoader, you can reduce `acc.load()` calls like:

```
    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint = {
            let acc = some_acc.load()?;
            acc.admin == *admin.key || acc.delegate_admin == *admin.key
        }
    )]
    pub some_acc: AccountLoader<'info, MyAccount>,
```

but if we have more constraints, we need to load again:

```
    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint = {
            let acc = some_acc.load()?;
            acc.admin == *admin.key || acc.delegate_admin == *admin.key
        },
        constraint = some_acc.load()?.is_active == IS_ACTIVE 
            @ErrorCode::NotActive
    )]
    pub some_acc: AccountLoader<'info, MyAccount>,
```

is there a way to load just once for the entire constraint decorator (other than moving the logic to the handler)? The above tends to blow out the heap quickly when dealing with large structs.

Bonus question: is `has_one` invoking a load call for each item? For example:

```
    #[account(
        mut,
        has_one = admin,
        has_one = something_else,
    )]
    pub some_acc: AccountLoader<'info, MyAccount>,
```

Does this also .load() twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to chain all your constraints into a single constraint. For example:

```
#[account(
    mut,
    constraint = {
       let acc = some_acc.load()?;
       (acc.admin == *admin.key || acc.delegate_admin == *admin.key) &&
        acc.is_active == IS_ACTIVE
     }
 )]
 pub some_acc: AccountLoader<'info, MyAccount>,
```

As for the second question, yes it does seem like each `has_one` instance invokes a load call. Reference [here](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/1a6b5066dfc52e4b60ba32d92059cafc4f5f637c/lang/syn/src/codegen/accounts/constraints.rs#L258). According to that piece of code, for each `has_one = target`, `target` is checked against [`some_acc.load()?.target`](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/1a6b5066dfc52e4b60ba32d92059cafc4f5f637c/lang/syn/src/codegen/accounts/constraints.rs#L276).

It doesn't look like there's any follow-up step to chain these checks for an `AccountLoader` either. That could be a possible improvement to Anchor's codegen logic.

Comment: Yeah I think this is correct, but it's a shame because if you chain conditionals in one constraint you lose the ability to emit a specific per-constraint error like `@ErrorCode::NotActive`

Comment: Yh. The current constraint format seems to be `constraint = impl fn() -> bool`. Extending that to also allow `constraint = impl fn() -> Result<bool>` could help here